# Avrdude config linux

Tags: eclipse, avr, avrdude, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying ubuntu 12.10. I want to use Eclipse IDE + avrdude. The problem is, that I have a custom ft232rl programmer, which is not included in standard avrdude configuration.
In windows I would add

```
#FTDI_Bitbang
programmer
  id    = "ftbb";
  desc  = "FT232R Synchronous BitBang";
  type  = ft245r;
  miso  = 3;  # CTS(11 PIN FT232R) 
  sck   = 5;  # DSR(9 PIN FT232R)
  mosi  = 6;  # DCD(10 PIN FT232R)
  reset = 7;  # RI (6 PIN FT232R)
;
```

this to avrdude.conf and it would work fine. But when I want to use it with AVR Eclipse Plugin it wouldn't show any available configuration in project-properties-avr-avrdude "new" button. I'm pressing the button and nothing happening. If I undo the changes in avrdude.conf it would show me list of available programmers and so on.

So how to use avrdude with custom programmer at least from terminal. And if it is possible, how to use it with eclipse?

Comment: Why don't you edit avrdude.conf manually, using a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

I have this configuration in `/etc/avrdude.conf` on Ubuntu:

```
programmer
  id    = "ftdi";
  desc  = "SparkFun FTDI Basic Breakout";
  type  = ft232r;
  miso  = 1;  # RXD
  sck   = 3;  # CTS
  mosi  = 0;  # TXD
  reset = 4;  # DTR
;
```

I think you should use your configuration in the same file.

Note: AFAIK avrdude doesn't support bitbanging with ft232 based devices without some patches, I built it from source following this [tutorial](http://doswa.com/2010/08/24/avrdude-5-10-with-ftdi-bitbang.html)

Comment: I can change this file "sudo gedit /etc/avrdude.conf" but then I would have problem in Eclipse (when clicking "new" button to set new configuration nothing happens). Try it, If you can.

Comment: @user1685095 I don't really use Eclipse, but this should work from the terminal, why do you add new configuration in Eclipse ? when Eclipse calls avrdude it will read this one by default

Comment: avrdude -p m8535 -c ftbb -U flash:w:Kur_Analog:i
error at /etc/avrdude.conf:1012 unrecognized character: "f"

It seems that it still doesn't know about my custom programmer. How to change that?